# Use TypeScript props keys for function component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code for example:

```
interface Props {
  children: any,
  className?: string,
  marginTop?: number,
  marginBottom?: number,
}

const Div = styled.div`
  ${(props: Props) => { return css`
      flex:1;
      ${props.marginTop && "margin-top: " + props.marginTop + "px;"};
      ${props.marginBottom && "margin-bottom: " + props.marginBottom + "px;"};
    `; 
  }}
`;


export const Column: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, className marginTop, marginBottom }) => {
  return (
    <Div className={className} marginBottom={marginBottom} marginTop={marginTop}>
      {children}
    </Div>
  );
};
```

Now I have to declare the props twice, once in Props and once in the exported component.

Is there a way to make all defined Props available as props for the component?

Just to make it clear, this is the part I'm trying to save my self to write again:

```
({ children, className marginTop, marginBottom })
```

Comment: You don't _have_ to destructure props, if you don't want to.

Comment: But then i won't be able to use those props on the component. isn't it?

Comment: No that isn't it. You can access them on the object, props.marginTop etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have access to all props (such as passing all of them down to a child component or a styled component), then as [what Jon suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213233/use-typescript-props-keys-for-function-component-props/71213271#comment125877930_71213233): do not destructure them as arguments. Instead, you can destructure it in the function body instead, if that is what makes you feel makes your code a little more readable:

```
export const Column: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <Div className="Column" {...props}>
      {children}
    </Div>
  );
};
```

This is no different than the *old school* way:

```
export const Column: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Div className="Column" {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </Div>
  );
};
```

---

p/s: For the purpose of typing, it might make sense to [define the props type directly on your styled component](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props), i.e. `const Div = styled.div<Props>`:

```
const Div = styled.div<Props>`
  ${(props) => { return css`
      flex:1;
      ${props.marginTop && "margin-top: " + props.marginTop + "px;"};
      ${props.marginBottom && "margin-bottom: " + props.marginBottom + "px;"};
    `; 
  }}
`;
```

Comment: Thank u very much! that makes my life so much easier and prettier :)